# Java Boolean Return Errors

Tags: java, boolean

I am new to java (and programming in general) and decided to make a program that checks whether a number is prime or not.

I made a working program:

```
import java.io.*;

public class PrimeChecker
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    int factor = 2;
    boolean check = true;
    System.out.println("Please input a number.");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(Reader.readLine ());

    if (number == 1)
    {
      System.out.println(number + " is neither prime nor composite.");
    }
    else
    {
      while (factor <= Math.sqrt(number))
      {
        if (number % factor == 0)
        {
          check = false;
          break;
        }
        factor++;
      }
        if (check)
        {
          System.out.println(number + " is a prime number.");
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println(number + " is a composite number (not prime).");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I read [this](http://codingbat.com/doc/java-if-boolean-logic.html), decided to play around with booleans a bit and changed it to this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class PrimeCheckerv2
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    int factor = 2;
    System.out.println("Please input a number.");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(Reader.readLine ());

    if (number == 1)
    {
      System.out.println(number + " is neither prime nor composite.");
    }
    else
    {
      while (factor <= Math.sqrt(number))
      {
        public boolean isPrime()
        {
          return (!(number % factor == 0));
        }
        factor++;
      }
        if (isPrime)
        {
          System.out.println(number + " is a prime number.");
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println(number + " is a composite number (not prime).");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I believe I did everything as instructed in the previously linked page I read but my new code is getting these 3 errors:

```
File: C:\Users\Aion\Documents\DrJava\Other\PrimeCheckerv2.java  [line: 19]
Error: Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration
File: C:\Users\Aion\Documents\DrJava\Other\PrimeCheckerv2.java  [line: 19]
Error: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
File: C:\Users\Aion\Documents\DrJava\Other\PrimeCheckerv2.java  [line: 19]
Error: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
```

I have looked through many questions on this site looking for something that might explain them but have found nothing. Can anyone tell me why I am getting these errors?

Comment: Have you looked at line 19?

Comment: @Zavior It could also be the one before...

Comment: You're declaring a method inside a method, you can't do that. You have `public boolean isPrime()` inside your while-loop inside `main`

Comment: Fixed the mistakes mentioned. Still getting errors

Comment: You're still declaring the `isPrime()` method inside your `main` method.

Comment: @mstbaum Oh I see. Now I am getting no errors. Problem is, it's not working properly :/

Comment: Step through your code with 8 as your `number`.  Why will your code say 8 is both prime and composite? Step through your code with 7 as your `number`. How many times does "7 is a prime number" print?

Comment: @mstbaum it only prints 8 is a prime number ( doesn't say anything about it being composite) and "7 is a prime number" is only printed once but I get what you're trying to day. My code is looking at every factor between 2 and Math.sqrt(number) and drawing separate conclusions from each one. Therefore, composite numbers are being labelled as both prime and composite. Also, numbers that do not have any factors between 2 and Math.sqrt(number) (2,3 and 4 (this one I don't get)) are not producing an output because the program does not have factors to work with. I don't know how to fix this however.

Comment: I already have a working program that checks for prime numbers. The whole point of this second one was to experiment with boolean return. Is it practical (or even possible) to make this program using a boolean method return statement or should I just stick to the way I did it in the first one?

Comment: Break the loop once you find out a number isn't prime. Then check if factor is greater than sqrt(number).  If it is, then `number` is prime.

Comment: @mstbaum Thanks! I also had to change int factor = 2 to int factor =1 to make 3 &4 work. Now, my program works with every number except 2.  It classifies 2 as a composite number for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: When `number=2` and `factor=2`, what is the result of `isPrime(2,2)`?

Comment: @mstbaum Yes but i thought factor can't go above Math.sqrt(number) without that number being labelled prime?

Comment: Right right, my bad. Well I have no idea what your code looks like now, so there's not a whole lot I can do.

Comment: Yea sorry, I did a rollback so that if someone looks at this question in the future, the answer will match the question and might help them. My current code is up now. p.s. If a mod sees this, I know we should have moved this to chat a while ago but I don't have enough rep for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.

First you define a new method inside another. That does not work in java.

```
   public boolean isPrime()
    {
      return (!(number % factor == 0));
    }
    factor++;
  }
```

So you have to put it under the rest of the code.

Second: the method must be static because you want to call that method from a static method.

Third: you have to pass parameters to the method:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number, int factor) {
    return number % factor != 0;
}
```

and you have to call it:

```
if (isPrime(factor, number))
```

So your class must look like:

```
public class PrimeCheckerv2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));

        int factor = 2;
        System.out.println("Please input a number.");
        int number = Integer.parseInt(Reader.readLine());

        if (number == 1) {
            System.out.println(number + " is neither prime nor composite.");
        } else {
            while (factor <= Math.sqrt(number)) {
                factor++;
                if (isPrime(factor, number)) {
                    System.out.println(number + " is a prime number.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(number
                            + " is a composite number (not prime).");
                }

            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int number, int factor) {
        return number % factor != 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Gaaah you beat me to it. Note: factor++ is not part of the function.

Comment: I modified my code and it is now exactly like what you wrote but I am still getting 3 errors. It now wants me to put semicolons in line 32 after isPrime, int number and int factor. Also, is it required that I put the boolean after the function or can I put it before where I declare my variables?

Comment: This code will print "___ is a prime number" for every factor tested when `number` is prime and will print both statements multiple times when `number` is composite